# how to write query search for this table in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My dbLink Access:

```
dbusername:a4930120_query12
dbpassword:query12
```

http://sql6.000webhost.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php?db=a4930120_query12&lang=en-utf-8&convcharset=iso-8859-1&collation_connection=utf8_unicode_ci&token=d05f552925d40687254ceaee7c636758&phpMyAdmin=ucDEM,ggxf8kAny6Ki9LD0YSYqf.

I want to retrieve data based on subject and Class.column name for classes(Class_I_V    Class_VI_VIII   Class_IX_X  Class_XI_XII).For example.my problem is how to write the search code for row no 8. they subject column contains(engg maths1,2,tpde,numerical methods,pqt,random pr...).like wise in my question is.Shall I want to give all keyword in my query(db column name is subject)?.if you see my subject column in my db.it contain all subject.I want to know how to write the proper code for this search.because user search with subject and class.As per my as per my level I have written the code.kindly make it proper.
Here is my code:

```
<form name="f1" action="" method="post">
Enter the subject to search:
<input type="text" name="search" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

search.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$search=$_POST['search'];
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT name,subject,place,expyrs,Class_I_V FROM tutor WHERE subject LIKE '%$search%' or  subject LIKE '%$search%'  or  subject LIKE '%$search%' or subject LIKE '%$search%' or subject LIKE '%$search%' or subject LIKE '%$search%' or subject LIKE '%$search%'or subject LIKE '%$search%'or subject LIKE '%$search%'or subject LIKE '%$search%'or subject LIKE '%$search%'or subject LIKE '%$search%'or subject LIKE '%$search%'or subject LIKE '%$search%'or subject LIKE '%$search%' Or Class_I_V LIKE '%Class I -V%' ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo ++$sno; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['subject'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['place'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['expyrs'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Class_I_V'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

Myurl:http://tutorquery.comuv.com/search.php

Type here:java or Class I -V

Answer (score 0):

This may be a sort solution, try this way using `REGEXP`

```
 SELECT * FROM `tutor` 
   WHERE
 subject REGEXP '^(engg maths1|tpde|numerical methods|pqt|random)$' 
 OR Class_I_V REGEXP 'Class_I_V'
```

See for more info that satisfy your requirements, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

**EDIT** Sorry at first i didn't see your database columns, i think you need **Full Text Search** in this case. see more here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: ok I will read that. I am asking have seen my db subject column I want to retrieve  the value based on subject  and class. if you see my subject column in my db it has lot values for that only I am asking you. Do I want to give query like subject LIKE '%$search%' or  subject LIKE '%$search%'  or  subject LIKE '%$search%' or subject LIKE '%$search%' or subject LIKE '%$search%' or Class_I_V LIKE '%Class I -V%' ".  like this? shall I want to give all keyword. I think you understand my question where I got stuck.

Comment: I have upload your query in webserver. check the link http://tutorquery.comuv.com/search.php  if I type java.the query is giving this one engg maths1|tpde|numerical methods|pqt|random. please check this .

Comment: your subject column contains comma seperated values??

Comment: Yes You are correct.Now I am planning to make the data separate by comma for example.Maths, Physics, Chemistry, Biology, Computer, like wise. I will change the  column  this engg maths1|tpde|numerical methods|pqt|random to  engg maths1,tpde,numerical, methods,pqt,random. Now can you guide me how to write the query for this.but subject contains lot of keyword .here is my problem? how make the query for this?

Comment: I think you need FIND_IN_SET,http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: can you write  a query for me. because  I have given my code. what I did still now.I think you got the concept.

Comment: In find_in_set(what I have write here) because subject column contains lot of values